# Can two machines running on Linux have same hostname?

Tags: hostname

I am trying to install linux on VMWARE where I have one more linux having one Oracle database installed on it. When I am trying to install other Linux Machine its asking for hostname. Can this hostname be same as the hostname of the installed Linux machine?

Answer (score 4):

It is preferred to have a unique hostname per machine.

- Having two machines in the same network (e.g. two VM guest machines) with the same hostname might lead to a real problem.

e.g. [vmware article - Two or more virtual machines with the same name](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2108769)

> - VMWARE solution:  To resolve this issue, rename the duplicate virtual machine to a unique name for each entity.

Note: each machine **must** have unique IP address.